# How to get the hostname of the router/access point I’m connected to?

Tags: linux, networking, hostname, conky

I’m using Linux Mint 17 and am making a [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) script. I’d like it to display the hostname of the router/access point I’m connected to. I just don’t know the Linux command to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Just realized the request was about a [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) specific script after posting this Bash-based answer. Leaving it up here just in case it’s useful.

Hostname for a router? Pretty sure that is not possible because most gateways don’t have a hostname assigned or even give out their hostname. But you can get the IP address using [`route`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route) piped through [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) and [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) like this:

```
route | grep "default" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

That will cleanly give you the raw IP address of the router. Now if you wanted the MAC address just do this using [`arp`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/arp) and that command mixed in with `grep` and `awk` in there as well again:

```
arp -a | grep $(route | grep "default" | awk '{ print $2 }') | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

And if you wanted to assign those values to Bash variables, just do this for the router IP address:

```
ROUTER_IP=$(route | grep "default" | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

And do this for the MAC address:

```
ROUTER_MAC=$(arp -a | grep $(route | grep "default" | awk '{ print $2 }') | awk '{ print $4 }')
```

And then you could use those assigned values by referring to `$ROUTER_IP` and `$ROUTER_MAC`. Like if you ran those two variable assignments just now just run these `echo` commands from the command line like this:

```
echo $ROUTER_IP
echo $ROUTER_MAC
```

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for. Check out a screenshot: [link](https://leetwanker.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/screenshot-from-2015-03-05-230428.png)

Comment: Think I'm finally done tinkering with it. Screenshot: [link](https://leetwanker.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/screenshot-from-2015-03-05-234407.png?w=614)

Answer (score 0):

Hostname and `ESSID` are two different things.

But if you're using [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net) and want `ESSID` it's something like this:

```
${offset 60}${font Ubuntu:size=12,weight:normal}${color1}Wlan0: ${wireless_essid wlan0}
```

Since it is now clear to me you actually mean the hostname of the external IP of an AP and not confusion of hostname and ESSID.

You can create a script and place it in your `.conky/script` directory

```
mkdir ~/.conky/scripts

gedit ~/.conky/scripts/hostname.sh

#!/bin/bash
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com | xargs dig +short -x
```

Make it executable `chmod +x ~/conky/scripts/hostname.sh`

add to your `.conkyrc` something like

```
${offset 60}${font Ubuntu:size=12,weight:normal}${color1}Hostname: ${execi 10000 ~/.conky/scripts/hostname.sh}
```

Comment: Sorry, should've specified that I wanted it for a wired connection.